# Adding a value in a conditional statement

Tags: r

I'm attempting to add a value (360) to all values within a dataframe column that are below 0. I assumed a simple statement would do. However, all this does is change the values to 360, not add the number to the existing value. I feel the solution is really simple but cant work out what it is. Thanks in advance.

```
##Example data
ID  <- c(1,2,3,4)
val <- c(-180,-150,170,-180)
df <- data.frame (ID,val)   

##My attempt
df$val[df$val < 0] <- + 360
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need subset the data from both the sides.

```
df$val[df$val < 0] <- df$val[df$val < 0] + 360
df

#  ID val
#1  1 180
#2  2 210
#3  3 170
#4  4 180
```

Using `ifelse` might be cleaner and easier to understand.

```
df$val <- df$val + ifelse(df$val < 0 , 360, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `data.table` this can be achieved by doing:

```
df[val < 0, val := val + 360]
```

or if you use `dplyr` instead:

```
df %>%
  mutate(val = ifelse(val < 0, val + 360, val))
```